# VBA Code is adding unnessary lines when using offset function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add lines depending on the input of an individual but when input is entered the first line works fine but every piece of information after adds extra lines to the excel sheet.

```
Sub InsertRows()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer


  Do
    'Retrieve an answer from the user
      x = Application.InputBox("Number of Lines Per skid", "Number of lines per skid", Type:=1)
      y = Application.InputBox("Skid Number", " What is the skid number", Type:=1)
      

    'Check if user selected cancel button
      If x = 0 Then Exit Sub
      Range("3:3", Range("A3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      
      Range("A3").Value = y
      Rows("3:268").Select
      Selection.RowHeight = 15.75
      Range("A3").Select
      Range("A3", Range("A3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("B3", Range("B3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("C3", Range("C3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("D3", Range("D3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("E3", Range("E3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("F3", Range("F3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("G3", Range("G3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
      Range("H3", Range("H3").Offset(x - 1, 0)).Merge
  Loop While x > 0 Or x < 24

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about why insertings multiple rows at once does not work but with a for-loop you´ll solve this.

```
Sub InsertRows()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

  Do
    'Retrieve an answer from the user
      x = Application.InputBox("Number of Lines Per skid", "Number of lines per skid", Type:=1)
      y = Application.InputBox("Skid Number", " What is the skid number", Type:=1)
      

    'Check if user selected cancel button
    
      If x = 0 Then Exit Sub
      
      'insert rows with a loop
      For row = 1 To x
          Range("3:3").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
      Next row
      
      Range("A3").Value = y
      
      'merge columns with a loop
      For col = 1 To 8
          Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3 + x - 1, col)).Merge
      Next col

  '??? make sure you loop is correct, this does not work properly
  'x will always be bigger than zero OR smaller than 24
  Loop While x > 0 Or x < 24

'just take all the cells an once, altering the RowHeight / no Selection needed.
Cells.RowHeight = 15.75

End Sub
```